# Get previous version of code in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I deploy very simple code to AWS Lambda using this commands:

```
zip http-endpoint lambda_function.py
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name 'http-endpoint' --zip-file fileb://http-endpoint.zip --region us-east-1
```

Is it possible to see previous version of code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can get data about your function using `get-function`. This returns a `code` object containing a `location` to your function's code artifact. [See docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html) => scroll down to output:

> Location -> (string)
>   The presigned URL you can use to download the function's .zip file that you previously uploaded. The URL is valid for up to 10 minutes.

Comment: and what if code was updated more than 10min before? e.g. it could be updated in the evening and during nighttime some issues might raise?

Comment: The 10 minutes are only relevant for the presigned URL, not the code itself (according to the docs).